# Completely locked out of MySQL via WAMP!

Tags: mysql, php

I've somehow managed to completely lock myself out of MySQL on WAMP. It seems all privileges are denied for all users. The only way I can get into MySQL is via the command prompt but without entering a user. From there, I quite literally cannot do anything... all privileges are denied. I've tried updating the root password to no avail.

I've also tried completely uninstalling WAMP as well as MySQL. After uninstalling MySQL, I deleted the data directories inside them to get rid of all the info there. After re-installing WAMP, the problem persists.

Attempts to access PHPMyAdmin results in:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: It appears that the root user's password is not being provided for the login attempt.

Comment: @KayakJim Good work, that's exactly what my error message says. Have you ever used WAMP before?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your my.cnf or my.ini and restart the mysql server:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

Then change the password in mysql.user table

```
update user set password = password('newpassword') where user = 'root'
```

Remove the skip line and restart the server. You will be able to login with the new password.

Comment: Using the second command in MySQL gives me an error: No database selected.

Comment: Change the second command to be:  update mysql.user set password = password('newpassword') where user = 'root'

Comment: @KayakJim @ghm1014 `UPDATE command denied...`

Comment: After MySQL is restarted with the skip-grant-tables option, are you able to access the database via PHPMyAdmin? If so, navigate to the mysql database, select the user table, and edit the root user record to reset the password. Be sure to select PASSWORD for the Function.

Comment: @KayakJim No, now I simply get 404 not found for all my localhost pages, including phpMyAdmin

Comment: Is Apache started?

Comment: Can you share your log mysql file?

Comment: @KayakJim yes, apache is started.. @ghm1014 I could, but the only log I have is from the most recent install I have of wamp. It only goes back about an hour or two... I started getting this problem yesterday.